# Functionality of csv_write.writerow in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I am using write_csv.writerow to write the data to a CSV. But I am getting everysingle digit or letter in a seperate Ex: `123` is writen as 1,2,3 and its  showing up as `1` `2` `3`. Here is the code I am using.

```
with open('nan.csv','w') as out:
    csvwriter=csv.writer(out)
    csvwriter.writerow(str(df['Purchase'].var()))
    csvwriter.writerow(str(df['Purchase'].std()))
    csvwriter.writerow(str(round(df['Purchase'].skew(),2)))
    csvwriter.writerow(str(round(df['Purchase'].kurt(),1)))
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong? Thank you

Comment: its an issue with `writerow()` it parses the string you pass as a list of characters to iterate through. I would stick to using `write(str())` for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects says:

> Writer objects (DictWriter instances and objects returned by the writer() function) have the following public methods. A row must be an iterable of strings or numbers for Writer objects and...

In your code, `str(...)` is sting object which is something like list that each elements are consist of one character, so writerow method writes each characters of the string one by one. This behavior is what OP think unexpected.

Instead of passing string object, pass iterable of strings something like list of string. To create list of string, you can convert `df['Purchase']` type as string and then convert its value to list.

```
df['Purchase'].astype(str).tolist()
```

sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import io

# create virtual csv file
f = io.StringIO('Purchase\n0,100\n1,200\n2,300')

# read from the csv file
df = pd.read_csv(f)
# In [41]: df
# Out[41]: 
#    Purchase
# 0         1
# 1         2
# 2         3

# create virtual file
f = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(f)

# write csv
writer.writerow(df['Purchase'].astype(str).tolist())

# read from virtual file
f.getvalue()
# In [74]: f.getvalue()
# Out[74]: '100,200,300\r\n'
```

There is also `to_csv` method in pandas:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html